# Proving $1+\tan^2(x)=\sec^2(x)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, proof-verification

If one is asked to prove $1+\tan^2(x)=\sec^2(x)$, this is how I would prove it. $$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=\frac{\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}=\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}=\sec^2(x)$$ and $$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=\frac{\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}=1+\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}=1+\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\right)^2=1+\tan^2(x)$$ Therefore $1+\tan^2(x)=\sec^2(x)$ So is my prove valid, and are there any easier ways to prove this?

Comment: This is hard to read.  Just divide $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2x=1$ by $\cos^2 (x)$.

Comment: Replace $\;\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} \frac{sin(x)}{cos(x)}=\;$ with $\;1+ \tan^2(x)=\;$ on the first line, then at the end of the line you are done.

Comment: My first impulse is to agree with @lulu and simply suggest that you apply the Pythagorean identity.  However, I suppose that if you have defined your trig functions from an IVP, then you might approach the problem as you have.  Maybe.  I guess the most relevant question here is **how have you defined $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$**?

Comment: Anyway, the proof is valid provided you can show that both functions agree at a point. Remember that two smooth functions having the same derivative can still differ by an additive constant on each connected component of their domain.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Checking agreement at a point would be necessary when taking an antiderivative, but in this case I don't think it's necessary; the derivative of a function is unique, and the proof just computes the derivative of $\tan x$ two different ways.

Comment: @davidk: oh, you are right. Thank you and sorry for my useless comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note simply that

$$1+\tan^2(x)=1+\frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x}=\frac{\cos^2x+\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x}=\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}=\sec^2(x)$$